# Removing menu bar in full screen mode in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have created a javascript game that I require to work in both fullscreen and none fullscreen mode. I have noticed in internet explorer 11 when the player presses F11 to go fullscreen that there appears to be a menu bar at the very top that interferes with the game. All other browsers work fine

I currently have the following JS code that reacts to toggling fullscreen

```
$(document).on("fullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange msfullscreenchange", function() {
    var isFullScreen = (typeof(document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement 
        || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement) !== "undefined");

    onChangeFullScreen(isFullScreen);
});
```

The onChangeFullScreen function isnt relevant as it simply queries the new reported window.innerWidth etc to reset the webgl view.

This game will be ran off of a server and therefore I cannot simply add iexplorer.exe flags when starting iexplorer. I am also not in control of the webpage that launches my index.html as it is a 3rd party company and im working inside an iFrame.

Thanks